# JSON responseText is not working in web content page

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-applications, visual-studio-2012

This function is working correctly in normal web form But not working/not returning any value in Web Content form while using master page.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
                debugger;
                $.getJSON(url, function callback(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    $('#ddlList').append('<p>Name : ' + jqXHR.responseText + '</p>');
                });
            });
```

Please have  a look this and advice me

Comment: is your `#btnSubmit` an ASP button with runat=server? If it is, the ASP.Net runtime will add some preamble to the client Id to make sure it is unique. Add a ClientIDMode="Static" to your button. Other option is to use `$('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>')`

Comment: No.. My button is  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="get data" />

Comment: Okay, look at your console to see if there are any JS errors. Is your `ddlList` `runat="server"`? You could also add an Error callback to your `getJSON` call to see if that is failing.

Comment: Can you post the C# server side method in addition to the javascript?

Comment: Its working in IE, But not working in firefox and chrome. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You need to find more info on why it's failing.  What does the console say in your browsers developer tools?

You can add this to get an alert if your getJSON fails

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            $.getJSON(url, function callback(data, status, jqXHR) {
                $('#ddlList').append('<p>Name : ' + jqXHR.responseText + '</p>');
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr) {
                console.log(jqxhr);
                alert(jqxhr);
            });
        });
```

then copy what is in your console to your question and you'll get a much better / more helpful answer.

Comment: You have the debugger line in there, is it opening the debugger?  can you confirm your ``.getJSON`` is actually being hit?

Comment: Yes. the control is coming inside the specified url. But its not coming inside the .getjson method and not binding the ddlList. ddlList is a div.

Comment: Its working in IE, But not working in firefox and chrome. Any idea??

Comment: When running your app, hit f12 in chrome to bring up the developer tools, then click on show console.  Show us what appears in the console when you run your app